# hiding flexslider nav arrows

Tags: html5-video, flexslider

1) I have a video website with a index.html (single-page), in which consider around 5 videos enclosed with a  tag. In this for the video carousel, flex-slider is used. when the first video plays, I would like to hide the flexslider navigation arrows hide automatically and show when each video ends. I tried and did it in css by making 'visibility:hidden', but it hides permanently, I want it to show/hide during the runtime. how do I do it?

2) For the same video website, I would like to hide the video play-back controls auto hide. During the video plays, the playback controls should hide and it should visible only when the video ends.

Please help me in completing it

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please, add code spippets to improve your question.

Comment: <div class="main-container">
<section class="cover fullscreen image-slider slider-all-controls">
         <ul class="slides">
                <div class="container v-align-transform">
         <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                    </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </li>
            <li class="vid-bg image-bg overlay">
       <div class="fs-vid-background">
       <video muted="" controls="controls">
               <source src="content/HZT 1.1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
       </video>
       </div>

Comment: there will be a repetition of 
<div class="fs-vid-background"> 
<video muted="" controls="controls"> 
<source src="content/HZT 1.1.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video> </div> tag to add videos. so for each videos the video carousel arrows to hide when the video plays and show when each video ends.

Comment: your HTML is not valid. Try again, please. I can append the code to the question if you write it. And tell me what is your CCS framework(s)?

Comment: @Alexander, thanks for the reply. can you please share your email so that I will share the full code, because there are more issues on this.

Comment: You could share the code using so public services as OneDrive, Google Drive, GitHub, JSFiddle or other and send the link.